# How to compare two std::istream references?

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11, clang, iostream

I am switching over compilers from GCC to Clang/LLVM and running into compilation errors I didn't experience before.

I have a class that looks something like this:

```
#include <iostream>

class foo {
    public:
        bar(std::istream& is) : _fp(is), _sCheck(is != std::cin) { /* ... */ }
    private:
        std::istream& _fp;
        bool _sCheck;
}
```

When I compile this file, I get the following error with `clang++`, where the initialization of the private variable `_sCheck` fails:

```
error: invalid operands to binary expression ('std::istream' (aka 
'basic_istream<char>') and 'istream' (aka 'basic_istream<char>'))

  (is != std::cin)
   ~~ ^  ~~~~~~~~
```

If both objects in this address comparison are of the same type, why is `clang++` returning an error, while `g++` does not?

I tried a `dynamic_cast` to make them both `std::istream&`, but this, too, returned an error:

```
error: invalid operands to binary expression ('std::istream' (aka 
'basic_istream<char>') and 'std::istream')

(is != dynamic_cast<std::istream&>(std::cin))
 ~~ ^  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I apologize in advance if this is a dumb question; I appreciate any pointers.

Comment: Have you by any chance switched from C++03 to C++11?

Comment: Yes, I am using `-std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++` flags.

Comment: My thinking here was that you were previously hitting `operator void *`, which would not be doing what you think, and is replaced in C++11 with `explicit operator bool`. But the error messages don't match up, so I'm not sure now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are using references, so you are comparing the objects and not the pointers as you maybe intended to. It seems GCC has an extension which allows you to compare `std::istream` objects, but this is not part of the standardized interface of [`std::basic_istream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream). Try:

```
_sCheck(&is != &std::cin)
```