# Is the std::istream type EqualityComparable?

Tags: c++, c++11, equality, istream

My question would have a boolean answer: yes or not. Whichever it would be, can someone explain how the following code is compiled by both GNU-g++ 4.9.2 and clang 3.5, while GNU-g++ 5.1.1 no longer accepts it, claiming that there is no matching `operator==`?

And how it could be changed, for this last compiler, in order to have the same results i.e. to have the `operator>>` able to distinguish, in such a simple way, whether
it is called by the standard input stream or by something else?

```
  # include <iostream>
  # include <fstream>

  struct S {};

  std::istream& operator >> (std::istream& i, S& s)
   {
    if(i == std::cin) std::clog << "this is standard input\n";
    else std::clog << "this is some other input stream\n";

    return i;
    }

  int main(int narg, const char ** args)
   {
    S s;
    std :: cin >> s;
    std::ifstream inp(args[1]);
    inp >> s;
    }
  // to be executed with the name of an existing
  // disk file on the command line....
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to compare two std::istream references?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18868060/how-to-compare-two-stdistream-references)

Comment: I don't understand what equality between streams could possibly mean. Identity, sure, but you have `&` for that.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: A reasonable (but completely hypothetical) example would be two `fstream`s comparing equal iff they access the same file.

Comment: @MSalters: I don't think that would make sense. You're comparing just one property of a vastly more complex entity. What about buffers? Flags? I/O modes? Cursors?

Answer (score 6):

No. There's no `operator==` that operates on `std::istream` objects.

Your being able to compare two `std::istream`s is an unfortunate consequence caused by the conversion function of `std::istream`, specifically [`operator void*`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool). In the expression `i == std::cin`, both `i` and `std::cin` are implicitly converted to `void*`, and the resulting values are compared. This is not really meaningful. This conversion function was removed in C++11 (replaced by an `explicit` conversion function, which won't be called in this situation), so if you enable the C++11 mode, the code will not compile.

As is stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18868060/how-to-compare-two-stdistream-references), if you want to check whether the reference `i` refers to `std::cin`, you can use `&i == &std::cin`.

Answer (score 2):

Standard C++ streams don't have `==`, `>`, `<` operators because they are not very meaningful in that context: what should "stream a is > than stream b" mean?

However, it shouldn't matter what type of `istream` you're dealing with: as long as you're not using specific methods defined in descendant classes (like `is_open`), base methods are shared (extracting, for instance). Whether you're extracting a `string` from a `istringstream` or a `ifstream`, you just do `in >> str` and let polymorphism take action.

If you really want to know the polymorphic type of the `istream`, you can use `typeid` or, simply, function overloading. In your case, with RTTI(`typeid`)

```
if ( typeid(in) == typeid(std::cin) )
    // cin
else
   // another istream type
```

Using overloading:

```
std::istream& operator >> (std::istream& i, S& s)
{
     std::clog << "this is standard input\n";   
     return i;
}

std::ifstream& operator>>(std::ifstream& i, S& s)
{
     std::clog << "this is some file input stream\n";
     return i;
}
```